# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] : The system cannot find the specified file

Tags: python-3.x

The following error occurred while running the inferenceRalesrgan_video.py file of Real-ESRGAN:

"python inference_realesrgan_video.py -i inputs/video/onepiece_demo.mp4 -n realesr-animevideov3 -s 2 --suffix outx2"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inference_realesrgan_video.py", line 403, in <module>
    main()
  File "inference_realesrgan_video.py", line 395, in main
    run(args)
  File "inference_realesrgan_video.py", line 297, in run
    inference_video(args, video_save_path)
  File "inference_realesrgan_video.py", line 254, in inference_video
    reader = Reader(args, total_workers, worker_idx)
  File "inference_realesrgan_video.py", line 76, in __init__
    pipe_stdin=True, pipe_stdout=True, cmd=args.ffmpeg_bin))
  File "C:\Users\Captain\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\ffmpeg\_run.py", line 285, in run_async
    args, stdin=stdin_stream, stdout=stdout_stream, stderr=stderr_stream
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\RealESR\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\RealESR\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the specified file
```

I haven't found a solution yet, I hope you can help me

Comment: Attempted to use absolute path, version ffmpeg python-0.2.0